# checking thruthness of overwritten valueOf not working

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I want to create a similar construction in my code.

```
var inList =  findItem(list, data); 

if(!inList) {

  var item = inList.item;

}

function findItem(list, data) {
  var item = list.find("[data-day='"+data.day+"']")

  // more code.

  // conditional return
  return {item: item, valueOf:function(){return false}};
}
```

But it doesn't work because overwriting valueOf doesn't play nicely with a simple truthfull check (in the way that I want it to work).

and having code like if(inList == false){} looks less clean imo. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What's `findItem` supposed to do and why do you try to create a falsy object (which don't exist)?

Comment: My list contains processed items, 
1 item in that list could've been created from 2 different datasets (I iterate over multiple datasets.)

So checking whether or not the dataset is in the list requires more than a simple search.
In my example if item had a length of greater than 0(in `findItem`), 
it could be the case that the dataset should still be added because another parameter in data was different than the one in list.

And when it's returned having the item is helpfull for adding it in the list later.

Comment: In that case, you really should just return the `item` and then check its `.length` instead of its truthiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not depend on code that uses valueOf,
if you wanted to do something where you are returning an object,
just add another property instead.

```js
var findResult = findItem(list, data);

if(!findResult.found) {
    var item = findResult.item;
}

function findItem(list, data) {
    var item = list.find("[data-day='"+data.day+"']");
    
    // more code.
    
    // conditional return
    return {item: item, found: false};
}
```

Then again, I forgot what I was doing 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean checks don't invoke `valueOf` - all objects are considered truthy. If you want to circumvent that, you'll have to invoke it yourself explicitly:

```
if (!inList.valueOf()) …
```